# Some packages failed to repair after reinstalling 12.10

Tags: package-management

I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10. It was not clean reinstall, since I wanted to save my personal files. However, since then, apport message keeps popping out about packages that failed to install, and cannot be installed for some reason.

I tried to look on other forums, but did not find any answers to this problem.

Just today I realized, I cannot even install some programs (such as VLC,..) from Software Center.

How can I get rid of them and reinstall them, so the system works fine again?

It is saying that it will be installed, but nothing happens

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.4-0ubuntu1) ale 2.0.4-0ubuntu1 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 6:0.8.3) ale 6:0.8.3.6ubuntu1 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 6:0.8.3) ale 6:0.8.3.6ubuntu1 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) ale 2.15-0ubuntu20 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) ale 2.4.10-0ubuntu1 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) ale 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) ale 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) ale 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) ale 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 se bude instalovat
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.0.15~) ale nebude se instalovat
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 ale nebude se instalovat
     Depends: libxcb-randr0 (>= 1.1) ale nebude se instalovat
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) ale nebude se instalovat
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) ale 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13
```

Does anybody knows solution to this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following commands (one at a time) in a terminal :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: The first one does not do anything and did not found anything to install, update...the message says: Package dependencies could not be resolved